# Combining location based probabilities from GPS data

Tags: spatial, dependent-variable, database

I'm working with GPS data and have billions of GPS points stored in a DB. I'd like to be able to use this to create a class likelihood function that I can use somewhere else as as a visualisation or classifier.

**Example:**
Let's say my GPS data is for cars and there are only three classes of cars; 4x4's, delivery trucks, and sports cars. Using my GPS database I've aggregated the data to find the total time spent on each street in a city, for each class. I've also found the speed distribution for each class, for each street.

On Rich Str, there are far more sports cars than delivery trucks. The location based probabilities are:

- P(*sports*) = 0.7
- P(*4x4*) = 0.2
- P(*delivery*) = 0.1

I also have calculated the speed distribution, so lets say an unknown vehicle is travelling at 30 KPH and the speed based probabilities for vehicles on Rich Str are:

- P(30 Kph | *sports* ) = 0.2
- P(30 Kph | *4x4*) = 0.4
- P(30 Kph | *delivery*) = 0.4

I also have different aggregates for time-of-day, direction of travel, colour of car etc.. all aggregated over that specific street (and all other streets).

Given an unknown vehicle was on Rich Street, travelling at 30 kph, was painted red, was travelling N etc. How should I go about finding the probability of it being a sports car

This seems like a simple combination of dependant probabilities but I also can't see how I can calculate some of the joint probabilities given the aggregates I have:

- P(class | 30 kph) This I have
- P(class | Red) This I also have
- P(class | 30 Kph and Red) This I don't have.

I know that the correct way to do this would be to go into the DB and fetch all measurements for Rich Str and then do some simple maths on how many vehicles out of the total were red, and moving at 30 kph etc but the size of the database means that I have to rely on precalculated aggregates rather than the raw samples.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to work out P(sports | 30Kph ∩ Red). Using Bayes' theorem, this is equal to:

P(30Kph ∩ Red | sports) * P(sports) / P(30Kph ∩ Red)

If *30Kph* and *Red* are conditionally independent (i.e. independent if you know the type of vehicle), then you can work out this probability from the aggregates you already have. For example:

P(30Kph ∩ Red | sports) = P(30Kph | sports) * P(Red | sports)

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly the probability would then come out to:
P(sports | 30Kph ∩ Red) = P(30Kph | sports) * P(Red | sports) * P(sports) / P(30Kph ∩ Red)

Any ideas on how to work out that last term: P(30Kph ∩ Red)?

Comment: Law of total probability. If it's reasonable to assume conditional independence, you have P(30Kph ∩ Red) = P(30Kph ∩ Red | sports)  * P(sports) + P(30Kph ∩ Red | 4x4)  * P(4x4) + P(30Kph ∩ Red | delivery)  * P(delivery).